# convert single dropdown list to multiple selection dropdown in javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, datatables

> Hi, I have a code that gives values in dropdown list and able to select only one value from list,but can we modify it so that can select multi values and render data. Actually I am doing this for data table plugin

```
this.api().columns().every( function () {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                     .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                     .on( 'change', function () {
                         var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                             $(this).val()
                         );

                        column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                        } );

                        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ){
                           select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                          } );
                      } );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `multiple`.

For example

```
<select name="dropdownName" multiple>    
//rest of code
```

Comment: using this I am only able to select multi values but how to show data as per selection@anon